# Семантична відмінність між поняттями "відчуття", "почуття" та "чуття"

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Слова «відчуття» та «почуття» широко вживані в українській мові, проте, напевно, не всі (подібно до мене) до кінця розуміють відмінність між ними. Наприклад, як сказати правильно: `відчуття несправедливості` чи `почуття несправедливості`?

Старий-добрий СУМ дещо плутається в поясненнях. До прикладу, в [першому](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidchuttja) випадку він каже про

> здатність відчувати, сприймати явища навколишнього світу.

В [другому](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochuttja):

> здатність відчувати, сприймати навколишнє середовище.

Уривок з газети [Хрещатик](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/71.htm) (71, [2000–2001](//mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/2017/10/31/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2-2000-2001/) роках), поданий на [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53394/26317.html), пояснює різницю так:

> Що таке відчуття? То відображення мозком людини властивостей предметів
>   об’єктивної дійсності, які безпосередньо впливають на органи чуття;
>   стан подразнюваного організму. (…) А почуття визначається як чітке і
>   ясне усвідомлення чогось у сфері психіки, моралі; емоції, вияви
>   душевного стану.

**АЄОА.** Вже знайомий нам СУМ [нагадує](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochuttja) про наступну штуку:

> Шосте **почуття** — здатність людини добре орієнтуватися в обставинах,
>   інтуїтивно приймати правильні рішення.

Як виборсатися з цієї суміші `відчуттів` та `почуттів`?

А ще, як зауважив [Yellow Sky](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/66/yellow-sky), існує `чуття`. Наскільки велика різниця між всіма поданими поняттями?

Comment: А ще ж є просто чуття.

Answer (score 6):

Виборсатися можна, хапаючись за "Психологічний словник" (Київ, 1982). Ось що він каже:

> **Відчуття** - психічний, процес, що полягає у відображенні мозком властивостей предметів і явищ об'єктивного світу, а також станів
>   організму при безпосередньому впливі подразників на відповідні органи
>   чуття. Їх класифікують за властивостями подразників і рецепторів:
>
> - відчуття зовнішніх подразників (екстероцептивні): зорові,
>     слухові, дотикові тощо;
> - відчуття внутрішніх подразників (інтероцептивні),або ж органічні (наприклад, відчуття спраги);
> - кінестатичні та статичні (відчуття рухів і положення тіла).

Ще одні небезпечні штуки -

> **Почуття** - психічні стани і процеси, в яких відображено емоційний бік духовного світу людини, її суб'єктивне переживання подій і
>   емоційне ставлення до навколишньої дійсності. Вони є суб'єктивним
>   способом інтерпретації об'єктивного світу. За способами перебігу
>   почуття поділяються на афекти, настрої та пристрасті. За змістом вони
>   бувають моральними, естетичними, соціальними тощо.

Аби зробити цей світ кращим, психологи вигадали ще й

> **Чуття** -
>
> - особливий психічний стан підсвідомого відображення явищ і подій, інтуїтивне передчуття їх;
> - особливе переживання, що супроводжується вдоволенням чи невдоволенням кимось або чимось. Чуття відбиває сам процес перебігу
>     емоцій і почуттів, відчування навколишнього, або ж причетність до
>     певної спільності (наприклад, *чуття родини*).

Отже, `почуття несправедливості`, але `шосте відчуття`.

Answer (score 1):

Леся Веклинець на «Культура мови на щодень» від інституту української мови НАН України.

Я заосновнював [її огляд](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine50-25.pdf)

> **Відчуття — почуття — чуття**
>
> [«Психологічний словник»](/a/798/585) (за редакцією [Віталія Войтка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%92%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)) подає таке тлумачення термінів: «**Відчуття** — психічний процес‚ що полягає у відображенні мозком властивостей предметів і явищ об’єктивного світу‚ а також станів організму при безпосередньому впливові подразників на відповідні органи чуття» (с. 29). Тобто відчуття відображають властивості речей і явищ‚ які існують незалежно від людини. А «**Почуття** — психічні стани і процеси‚ в яких відображено емоційний бік духовного світу людини‚ її суб’єктивне переживання подій і емоційне ставлення до навколишньої дійсності» (с. 129). У почуттях ми переживаємо своє ставлення до
>   навколишніх речей і явищ. *Відчуття* говорять про самі речі‚ а *почуття* — про те‚ як людина ставиться до цих речей‚ який стан вони викликають у ній. Точне термінологічне значення зафіксоване в таких словосполученнях: ***відчуття*** зорові‚ слухові‚ дотикові‚ нюхові‚ смакові‚ відчуття болю‚ тепла і тому подібне; ***почуття*** неусвідомлене‚ радості‚ кохання‚ сорому та інше.
>
> Інший приклад: «Я *чую* звук‚ і він збуджує в мені радісне *почуття*. Але радість‚ яку я *почуваю*‚ існує тільки в мені. Коли б я не *чув* звуку‚ то не радів би». Саме таке розрізнення значень споріднених слів ілюструють приклади у «Словнику української мови»: «Приємно відчувати запах прілого листя і соснової смоли» ([СУМ‚ І‚ с. 662](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidchuvaty)).
>
> Дійсні й вагомі мають бути поняття‚ пов’язані з *почуттям добра‚ істини‚ справедливості*. Ці почуття стосуються морально-етичних категорій (у психології йдеться саме про моральні *почуття*). У загальновживаній мові‚ на відміну від спеціальної‚ наукової‚ слово *почуття* можна замінити синонімами. [«Практичний словник синонімів української мови»](http://zosh6.at.ua/praktichnij_slovnik_sinonimiv_ukrajinskoji_movi.pdf) [Святослава Караванського](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (Київ‚ 1993) подає такий синонімічний
>   ряд до слова «почуття — чуття‚ почування‚ емоції‚ поривання душі; (міри) усвідомлення‚ розуміння; (небезпеки) передчуття; (гумору) схильність до; любов‚ кохання». Отож‚ можна сказати не *почуття добра*‚ а *усвідомлення*‚ *розуміння*. У своїх вчинках людина має керуватися розумінням‚ *усвідомленням* того‚ що треба робити добро. Відомий учений і мовознавець [Павло Білецький-Носенко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) писав: «Думай добро‚ роби добро і буде добро». Це розуміння‚ усвідомлення‚ почуття має бути притаманне людині.
>
> На перший погляд‚ близьке за значенням до слів *відчуття‚ почуття* виступає і слово *чуття*. Як термін він має чітке трактування. Сучасні лексичні норми визначають таку його сполучуваність: *чуття мови‚ чуття колективу‚ художнє чуття‚ естетичне чуття* та інше. Не зовсім точно вживати вислови *чуття зору‚ чуття смаку‚ вібраційне чуття* та інше‚ які позначають *відчуття зорові‚ вібраційні* тощо.
>
> У психології термінологічного змісту набув вислів *шосте відчуття*‚ який саме в такій формі усталився в сучасній мовній практиці.